# Insert Multiple records in BigQuery using WSO2

Tags: google-bigquery, wso2-esb

I am using BigQuery Connector in WSO2 to insert multiple records in BigQuery cloud.

I followed this [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+Table+Data+in+BigQuery#WorkingwithTableDatainBigQuery-insertAllTableData) and was able to insert a single record successfully.

**First** I tried to pass multiple records by separating them using a comma.
However, in this case, only the first record gets inserted and other records are skipped.

Please note that no error is returned in this case.

My Json message with multiple records:

```
{"insertId":"101","json":{"NAME":"Vishal_101","ADDRESS":"UK","ID":"vbordia"}},{"insertId":"102","json":{"NAME":"Vishal_102","ADDRESS":"UK","ID":"vbordia"}}
```

**Second** I tried this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll?apix_params=%7B%22projectId%22%3A%22jlr-dl-edw-dev%22%2C%22datasetId%22%3A%22JLR_DL_EDW_DIM_VCARS%22%2C%22tableId%22%3A%22CMMS_TEST_TABLE%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22rows%22%3A%5B%7B%22insertId%22%3A%22z1%22%2C%22json%22%3A%7B%22NAME%22%3A%22Vishal_z1%22%2C%22ADDRESS%22%3A%22UK%22%2C%22ID%22%3A%22vbordia%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22insertId%22%3A%22z2%22%2C%22json%22%3A%7B%22NAME%22%3A%22Vishal_z2%22%2C%22ADDRESS%22%3A%22UK%22%2C%22ID%22%3A%22vbordia1%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D) which explain how to build multiple records.
However, this time I get an invalid response from BigQuery. Since the response message is not well explanatory I am unable to understand the cause.-

Messagean :

```
{
"rows":
  [
    {
      "insertId":"209",
      "json": 
        {
          "NAME": "NewRow1",
          "ADDRESS": "NewAddr",
          "ID": "123"
        }
    },
    {
      "insertId":"210",
      "json": 
        {
          "NAME": "NewRow2",
          "ADDRESS": "NewAddr",
          "ID": "123"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Error Message Returned from BigQuery :

```
{
"insertErrors": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "errors": [
        {
          "reason": "invalid",
          "location": "",
          "debugInfo": "",
          "message": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone please help me here.What is the correct way of inserting multiple records in BigQuery via Wso2.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the 2nd error is coming when running the insertAll from the 2nd [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll)?

Comment: Yes Tamir . I have treid many other ways of inserting but nothing is working. Since there is no error message being returned from BigQuery I am unable to find what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in WSO2 Bigquery connector. We have raised with WSO2 and they have now released new version of connector which is capable of inserting multiple records.You can find the latest version at WSO2 market place.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data I created a test table in my project

[image]

And used the [API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll) to upload your example data as follow:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myproject/datasets/dataset/tables/testInsert/insertAll' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"rows":[{"insertId":"z1","json":{"NAME":"Vishal_z1","ADDRESS":"UK","ID":"vbordia"}},{"insertId":"z2","json":{"NAME":"Vishal_z2","ADDRESS":"UK","ID":"vbordia1"}}]}' \
  --compressed
```

using this `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.testInsert` LIMIT 1000
```

I confirmed the data is in the table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tamir for your quick response. I do not have access to insert data directly into BigQuery console and I think the way you inserted is directly using BigQuery API, but I am trying to find a way to insert the rows using an ESB tool WSO2. If you have any idea about this,please suggest me.

Comment: Below is the single record which is being inserted successfully when trying via WSO2 tool.

{"insertId":"101","json":{"NAME":"Vishal_101","ADDRESS":"UK","ID":"vbordia"}}

But I am unable to insert multiple rows and have no idea how to create json message for multiple rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with WSO2, maybe others can help on this, but I can assure you the bare API support multiple inserts. One workaround I might suggest is to create an external loop in WSO2 assuming this is possible and stream the data row by row as you confirm a single insert is working

Comment: Thanks Tamir. I will try the work around suggested by you. But there must be a way to pass multiple rows in a single query .Has anyone faced this issue in WSO2 please?